# Django Model Relationship with Multiple Classes

Tags: python, django, models

Sure the answer's out there but I've struggled to find the search terms! This is my first Django project and I can't seem to come up with a logical model structure...

```
Domain-->* Region-->* [Domain]Network
```

Within a **Domain** there are various **Regions** and each region can have a number of **Networks** (that should only be of the underlying **Domain** specific model, as each **Domain** has a specific **Network** layout).
Each **Network** has it's own specific fields (although also share some common, so could inherit somehow?)

More **Domains** (and so **Networks**) will be created in the future so should be able to scale. **Regions** may overlap (so Region2 may also be in DomainABC) but again Domain-specific Networks will be applied.

### Example:

If the Domain is ABC, you should only be able to associate ABCNetworks to Regions within that domain. Likewise the XYZ Domain should contain regions that can only have XYZNetworks.

> **DomainXYZ:**
>
> - Region1
>
>   - XYZNetwork1
>   - XYZNetwork2
>   - XYZNetwork3
> - Region2
>
>   - XYZNetwork4
>   - XYZNetwork5
> - Region3
>
>   - XYZNetwork6
>   - XYZNetwork7
>
> **DomainABC:**
>
> - Region101
>
>   - ABCNetwork1
>   - ABCNetwork2
>   - ABCNetwork3
> - Region102
>
>   - ABCNetwork4
>   - ABCNetwork5
> - Region103
>
>   - ABCNetwork6
>   - ABCNetwork7

Maybe a drop down when creating the Domain to select the Network model (OneToOne?), that then forces the Region to only be able to create [Domain]Networks?
Or just a complete rethink!?

### Code:

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    domain_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_name


class Region(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name


class XYZNetwork(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    network_name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    network_data = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    useless_number = models.IntegerField()
    network_secondary = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    crazy_network = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.network_name


class ABCNetwork(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    network_name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    network_data = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.network_name
```

Comment: What's your question? You've already had a bunch of models. What's wrong with those?

Comment: How can I tie the Domain to Network? At the minute I could create ABCNetworks for an XYZ Domain and vice-versa. Or should this just be a front-end restriction? It just doesn't look right I guess...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I'd just add some validation to your `Domain`s. 
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I could 'link' Domain to Network. For example if I were to count the Networks in a Region, I'd have to write a different function for each [Domain]Network model. And hardcode which model to look for, so one for `self.abcnetwork_set.all()`, one for `self.xyznetwork_set.all()` etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "how to inherit common fields" use 'abstract=True' see this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Thanks, thought there'd be some inheritance, I'll give that a go!